# PhoneGap SqlLite getting around 5mb limit

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have a question regarding how to get around the 5mb limit for sqllite in phonegap. Most of the answers on Stack didn't meet my needs, so that's why I'm asking this.

Basically, I'm wondering if you can split your data out into 2 databases and have double the limit -10MB. This phonegap app will be on both Android 2.3+ and IOS 5+, so we can't make any assumptions on higher device-specific limits. Also, we don't have the time to convert our code to use the SQLite Phonegap plugin, which I know would otherwise be a solution.

Splitting the data into 2 DB's seems like the quick solution, but I'm not sure if the embedded browser still looks at the TOTAL storage used for the app in general.

Comment: It's spelled SQLite, one L, upper case SQL. Why did you rollback?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any direct ways around that limit - have you tried the split database option? - but it probably wouldn't help much anyway -  with larger amounts of data you will likely run into problems with the backup system trying to copy database files in the small amount of time available as the app shuts down.

Which SQLite plugin have you looked at? Some versions are a lot closer to the web sql api than others - I'm using https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin and the below code from my own app is the only part that is different when using the plugin.

```
if (app.isPhonegap) {
    console.log("using native db");
    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("ExampleDb", "", "Example local database", 1000000);

} else {
    console.log("Using web db");
    db = openDatabase("ExampleDb", "", "Example local database", 1000000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with HTML5 Storage on devices, it will not allow you to increase the size. Have a look with this solution:

[Solved iOS Database Size Limitation of 5MB (using Plugin)](http://blog.heldes.com/html5/solved-ios-database-size-limitation-of-5mb-using-plugin/)

He is using a plugin to solve the limitation of 5 mb database on mobile, but this plugin is using PhoneGap framework.

Hope this will help you to solve you problem.

Cheers